# Why do not you update the store data correctly after a dispatch from Vue Router?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have some routes protected in vue-router, this I do through the meta property of the routes in vue-router.

When I load the index route, that is, all the records show me the edit button since at that moment I have this permission, if I update that user, I go to another panel with the admin user and I remove said permission. Now I go to the normal user and I give in the edit button of my table, I should send me to a route 403 since I do not have that permission at that moment, but it does not, just to the next navigation to another route I update the permissions. How do I solve this?

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.dispatch('ME'); // get permissions before navigate route
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.permission_name)) {
        // I check if the route permits, otherwise send to route 403
        if(!store.getters.containsPermission(to.meta.permission_name)){
            next({name : '403'})
        }
        else{
            next()
        }
    }
    else{
        next()
    }
})
```

The permissions are in the database from the backend I use Laravel and Laravel Permissions, by modifying the permissions for that user from another administrator user, and doing the `store.dispatch('ME');` I get the new permissions, which I thought that by calling the dispatch before evaluating the meta, it would arrive correctly to the `next({'403'});`

I hope you understand me, if not, do not hesitate to comment.

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match the actual question. You'll get better responses if you can make it more appropriate

Comment: You'll either need to continuously check for updated user permissions or somehow push them to your app (websockets, etc). When you say _"if I update that user"_, what does that mean? Where is the data stored?

Comment: @Phil I tried to focus better on the title, but is the problem understood? Is it supposed that if I get the updated permissions before verifying the goal, would it work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put permissions in your store. I, or someone else like me who is crafty, could just insert full permissions for your application whenever I wanted. Instead, query with the API for them before **every** route change.

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  try {
    await api.get('permissions', { params: permissions: to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.permission_name }})

    next()
  } catch (e) {
    next({ name: '403 })
  }
})
```

And just handle it server side.

Comment: This would be for routing, but I also use permissions to control elements of my components. Is it a global solution or how is that focused? , So modify the store, from the backend the validation for each request with the permissions is increased.

Comment: I would say that it doesn't matter for the component-level interactions, only when route changes and interacting with your API. So you could, in fact, reference the store for those permissions for a UX driven approach, but always validate the permissions when receiving an API request server-side thereafter.

Comment: All iterations with the API of my backend are controlled, by policies and permissions. At the UI level, the most you can do is make one item more visible and not obtain data.

Comment: Then I would say that hydrating the store is the correct way to go. But always re-fetch per request and compare *from the request response* and **not** from the **store** at the route level.

Comment: I update the store, that's what I do, now I try to update with the dispatch, but the store seems to be updated to the next request. That is my doubt and I do not know how to solve it, since I would not be acting correctly.

Comment: Look closely at how I used `async/await` above. Apply the `await` to the `dispatch`.

Comment: I'll check it to see how it goes, although I opted to hear the error 403 of axios and redirect.

Comment: My point is that you're never `waiting` for the `dispatch` to go off so the `next` function goes off immediately. `dispatch` returns a `promise`. so if you await that, then your code will function correctly at this point. But you still have the issue in that you're relying on the store to give you back the permission. Don't. Return the permissions from `store.dispatch()` in `Promise.resolve(data)` so you can await the response in the `beforeEach` and use the `raw server response`.